# Enterprise Architect code generation - compose - membervariable as array

Tags: arrays, code-generation, class-diagram, enterprise-architect, object-composition

I've this class diagram
[image: class diagram compose]

and the multiplicity 1 : 0..*

The generated code from this model:

```
public class TestKlasseB {
    public TestKlasseB(){
    }
    ~TestKlasseB(){
    }
}//end TestKlasseB

public class TestKlasseA {
    public TestNameSpace.TestKlasseB m_TestKlasseB;    //this line
    public TestKlasseA(){
    }
    ~TestKlasseA(){
    }
}//end TestKlasseA
```

I would like the member variable in `TestKlasseA` as an array ( `m_TestKlasseB` )

```
public TestNameSpace.TestKlasseB[] m_TestKlasseB;
```

What I need to change?

--

Regards
raiserle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways to do that.

Either you define your association as an attribute (member variable) and got to its detail properties and select Attribute is a Collection with [] as type.

[image: Attribute as Collection]

Or you go to source code engineering options and add a default collection class (e.g. List<#TYPE#> ) there under your language (Ctrl + F9, Source code Engineering -> Java -> Default Collection Class).
[image: Default Collection class]

Comment: can you explain me this with some pictures

Comment: I have added some screenshots.

Comment: Thanks. Its perfect! The second way looks fine.